# Local CDH install still downloading

Tags: cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am installing `CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42-el6` on `CentOS 6.5` with cm.
I've done with the rpms installation, and copy following file to

```
/opt/cloudera/parcel-repo` folder:
CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42-el6.parcel
CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42-el6.parcel.sha
manifest.json
```

i have verify the hash is correct.

but in the CDH5 install step, it still trying to download something and very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove CDH-5.8 parcels from /opt/cloudera-parcel-repo and move those files to any of other directories. Ex:- To your home and create a directory called `cdh`. Start simple python server using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8800`. Make a note of server address and port

Now log in to the Cloudera Manager. Enter above server and port details in parcel selection more details `Remote Parcel Repository URLs` Then click O.K. Now start installation

For more info refer this link [Cloudera installation Offline using parcels](http://bigdata-tips.blogspot.in/2016/03/cdh-552-installation-on-rhelcent-os-71.html)